# Reliable message delivery versus guaranteed message delivery

Tags: messaging, reliable-message-delivery

Is there a difference between a reliable message delivery system and a guaranteed message delivery system?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is:

A reliable message delivery system uses a protocol and/or a reliable transport mechanism and depending on its scope, it retransmits messages which failed (for a few times) to arrive or even persists messages between sessions/restarts.

Apart from the realm of marketing departments, there is - in contrast - no such thing as a guaranteed message delivery system. You doubt? Simply detonate the receiving/transmitting/both box while the message is being transmitted. It will never arrive.

Comment: This reminds me of the scene in Harry Potter where the messages from Hogwarts are delivered in a very close approximation to "guaranteed", much to the chagrin of the Dursleys....

Comment: Here, have an upvote for detonating computers to prove a point. But to be absolutely sure, can you upload a video to showcase your idea?

Comment: Being unable to spare my "boxes" for repeated takes of such a video I assure you that the procedure complies to all state-of-the-art environmental protection requirements, such a lead-free-casings for the nuclear device...